# window 10, how can I get terminal tab in Geany

Tags: python, geany, geany-plugin

I have been studying python crash course using Geany as the book says, but I recently found out there's no "terminal" tab in my Geany, only status, compiler, messages and scribble. I did a lot of research on line but couldn't find any way to add it in, the website mentioned VTE, and some suggestion for linux, and my computer is window 10. I've been struggle to find the way to add it in but no success, what should I do? Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Embedded terminal emulation (VTE)* is the missing feature in the Windows build as said in [Geany wiki](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/win32/running).

You can find more information about this case *"[Terminal/console feature on Windows #675](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/675)"*

You tagged this question *Python*, it looks like `GeanyPy` gives a Python REPL, look in the [mentioned issue above](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/675).

Comment: I will just have to use windows terminal then, thank you for respond

Comment: As you are new here, if an answer resolve your problem, do not forget to accept it (-;